# Can I use jQuery to map a javascript array to a collection of <li></li> elements?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of error messages: json.Errors

Is there a way that can create the following from this array using
jQuery?

```
    <ul class="message" id="message">
        <li>message1</li>
        <li>message2</li>
    </ul>
```

In the past I did something like the following code:

```
$.map(json.Errors, function (error) {
   return error + '</br>';
}).join('');
```

I am not sure it helps but maybe someone knows how $.map could
be used for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$.each(json.Errors, function(i,e) {
    $('#message li').eq(i).text(e);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QmeDa/).

This, of course, requires a 1:1 relationship between the `li` elements and the `json.Errors` array.

If you wanted to create the `li` elements (rather than rely on their already being present), then I'd suggest:

```
$.each(json.Errors, function(i, e) {
    $('<li />').text(e).appendTo('#message');
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QmeDa/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thanks David. How could I clear the existing error messages <li></li> elements before I add the new ones?

Comment: Simply use `$('#message').empty();` before calling the  `$.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying it's an array, why not use a simple join?

```
$('#message').html('<li>' + json.Errors.join('</li><li>') + '</li>');
```

Comment: This is the best solution in case `json.Errors` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var errUl = $('<ul class="message" id="message">' + $.map(json.Errors, function(error) {
    return '<li>' + error + '</li>';
}).join('') + '</ul>');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2baEv/1/)

This will create a single jQuery object containing the parsed HTML data of your unordered list, `errUl`.

Ref http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use map you could do something similar to the below

```
$("#message").empty().append($(json.Errors).map(function (msg){
  return $("<li>" + msg+ "</li>");
}));
```

Or use each

```
$("#message").empty().append($(json.Errors).each(function (){
  return $("<li>" + this+ "</li>");
}));
```